# How to remove the specific file buffer from vim?

Tags: linux, vim

I opened the files using **:e** or **gf**(Esc mode) commands in vim.
when I use **:ls** ,It list the all the opened file buffers.
How to remove the specific file buffer from vim?

Comment: For future reference, there is no "Esc mode".  You are describing "normal" mode or "command" mode.  That will make searches you do in the future a little more productive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

:bdelete f1.txt

see http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Vim_buffer_FAQ for details